# phpunit replies unrecongnized option --env

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I was trying to execute my test cases using phpunit command in laravel but the command replies the following

```
$ phpunit --env=testing
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

unrecognized option --env
```

Is this familiar to someone please help me.

Edit:

The following is the help for the command where the option does not exist. What should I do?

```
$ phpunit --help
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [switches] <directory>

  --log-junit <file>        Log test execution in JUnit XML format to file.
  --log-tap <file>          Log test execution in TAP format to file.
  --log-json <file>         Log test execution in JSON format.

  --coverage-clover <file>  Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format.
  --coverage-html <dir>     Generate code coverage report in HTML format.
  --coverage-php <file>     Serialize PHP_CodeCoverage object to file.
  --coverage-text=<file>    Generate code coverage report in text format.
                            Default to writing to the standard output.

  --testdox-html <file>     Write agile documentation in HTML format to file.
  --testdox-text <file>     Write agile documentation in Text format to file.

  --filter <pattern>        Filter which tests to run.
  --testsuite <pattern>     Filter which testsuite to run.
  --group ...               Only runs tests from the specified group(s).
  --exclude-group ...       Exclude tests from the specified group(s).
  --list-groups             List available test groups.
  --test-suffix ...         Only search for test in files with specified
                            suffix(es). Default: Test.php,.phpt

  --loader <loader>         TestSuiteLoader implementation to use.
  --printer <printer>       TestSuiteListener implementation to use.
  --repeat <times>          Runs the test(s) repeatedly.

  --tap                     Report test execution progress in TAP format.
  --testdox                 Report test execution progress in TestDox format.

  --colors                  Use colors in output.
  --stderr                  Write to STDERR instead of STDOUT.
  --stop-on-error           Stop execution upon first error.
  --stop-on-failure         Stop execution upon first error or failure.
  --stop-on-skipped         Stop execution upon first skipped test.
  --stop-on-incomplete      Stop execution upon first incomplete test.
  --strict                  Run tests in strict mode.
  -v|--verbose              Output more verbose information.
  --debug                   Display debugging information during test execution.

  --process-isolation       Run each test in a separate PHP process.
  --no-globals-backup       Do not backup and restore $GLOBALS for each test.
  --static-backup           Backup and restore static attributes for each test.

  --bootstrap <file>        A "bootstrap" PHP file that is run before the tests.
  -c|--configuration <file> Read configuration from XML file.
  --no-configuration        Ignore default configuration file (phpunit.xml).
  --include-path <path(s)>  Prepend PHP's include_path with given path(s).
  -d key[=value]            Sets a php.ini value.

  -h|--help                 Prints this usage information.
  --version                 Prints the version and exits.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know your PHPUnit version is VERY outdated, Nov 2014. Please update.

Also, what are you trying to do with the --env? You can configure the application environment in the phpunit.xml in the root directory like so:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    ... more variables
</php>
```

Comment: True. I followed the laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/testing where this option is mentioned to test. I found out if I run "./vendor/bin/phpunit" then without the option it tries to execute the tests

Comment: “This file will override the .env file when running PHPUnit tests or executing Artisan commands with the --env=testing option.“ this means OR “phpunit commands” OR “artisan command with the —env parameter”. So not phpunit —env but  php artisan —env :)